# joomla with mssql warning

Tags: sql-server, joomla, database-connection

"Components / Messaging / New Private Message " page "Select User" the following error comes when I do . How can I solve this?

Error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column '#__users.lastResetTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. SQL=SELECT a.* FROM [#__users] AS a LEFT JOIN #__user_usergroup_map AS map2 ON map2.user_id = a.id WHERE map2.group_id IN (7,8) AND id NOT IN (232) GROUP BY [a].[id],[a].[name],[a].[username],[a].[password],[a].[block],[a].[sendEmail],[a].[registerDate],[a].[lastvisitDate],[a].[activation],[a].[params],[a].[email] ORDER BY [a].[name] asc [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column '#__users.lastResetTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>   SQL=SELECT * FROM ( SELECT a.* , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [a].[name] asc) AS RowNumber FROM [#__users] AS a LEFT JOIN #__user_usergroup_map AS map2 ON map2.user_id = a.id WHERE map2.group_id IN (7,8) AND id NOT IN (232) GROUP BY [a].[id],[a].[name],[a].[username],[a].[password],[a].[block],[a].[sendEmail],[a].[registerDate],[a].[lastvisitDate],[a].[activation],[a].[params],[a].[email] ) A WHERE A.RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 20
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column '#__users.lastResetTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. SQL=SELECT a.* FROM [#__users] AS a LEFT JOIN #__user_usergroup_map AS map2 ON map2.user_id = a.id WHERE map2.group_id IN (7,8) AND id NOT IN (232) GROUP BY [a].[id],[a].[name],[a].[username],[a].[password],[a].[block],[a].[sendEmail],[a].[registerDate],[a].[lastvisitDate],[a].[activation],[a].[params],[a].[email] ORDER BY [a].[name] asc

Comment: which joomla version you are using?

Comment: joomla 3.5.1 php 7.0.7 mssql 2008

Comment: Did you update your website recently? Was the issue caused by an update?

Comment: yes many times, ı think component not supported mssql